# Oracle Apex 19.2 How to change app-icon colour on the login page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am attempting to change the app-icon colour on my apex apps login page.

I can see the css that the icon is using  here:

```
.app-icon {
    background-image: url(app-icon.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-color: #6E8598;
}
```

but when I change the background-color the background changes but then I lose the icon.

I am trying to learn CSS so any help of the correct way to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Any idea of how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The background color specified in the CSS is only used as long as the SVG file hasn't been loaded. You also have to change the SVG file.

1. Go to Shared Components -> Static Application Files,
2. download app-icon.css and app-icon.svg.
3. Edit the files with a Text editor and replace the existing Background color #6E8598 with the color hex code use want to use.
4. Upload the modified files by clicking the Upload File button
5. Run the app again

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for much. Really appreciate the help. Worked a treat.